# How to send post value on form action URL in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to send all value of my form on action url like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com?action=myform&redirect_url=thank-you

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="action"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Please, anyone can help me solving this problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use GET Method.

```
<form method="GET" action="">
<input type="text" name="action"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: If i use get method then show blank page. I use this form on wordpress plugin

Answer (score 0):

try to use get method , not post method

post method posts values in a hidden format ,
if you use get method you can see the values in the url but Get is not secure way of sending data

```
 method="GET"
```

if you use Get method you can see the values like the following

```
http://www.mywebsite.com?action=myform&redirect_url=thank-you
```

Comment: If i use get method then show blank page. I use this form on wordpress plugin